# Watch Your Words?

Tags: colloquialisms

Today I was told to *watch my words.*

I responded that hearing my words is easy, watching the words, not so much.

Is there a definition of *watch* to mean *pre-plan* or *compose with care??*

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/watch#Verb Definition 6 (verb) To attend to dangers to or regarding. *Watch what you say*

Comment: Agreed; guard your lips, watch your mouth, watch your words all connote vigilance, or keeping a watchful eye on. Not really an idiom.

Comment: @medica No, but it seems to feature in some idioms: *watch your step* etc, though

Comment: See also [ell.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary [*watch*](http://www.oed.com.ezproxy.is.ed.ac.uk/view/Entry/226076?rskey=tSgIgd&result=2#eid) can mean "to exercise care, caution, or restraint about something".

This is the usage we find in

- watch your pennies
- watch that hole over there
- watch your weight
- watch your back
- watch your step
- watch your Ps and Qs
- watch the time

and other such sayings.

It's also the meaning of *watch* in the Original Poster's example: *watch your words!* Watch here doesn't mean *plan* or *compose with care*. It means:

> *Be cautious and restrained about which words you use - otherwise you might get into trouble!*